# I'd like to know how wordpress developers write code local and check the result

Tags: wordpress

I’m trying to customize my Wordpress website. It’s already on live and I’d like to change some features.

For doing this, I wanted to do coding on local, not on wp-admin page directly. Because I needed to use GitHub for doing version control. After checking the result on local, push to live site.

So I created local environment using XAMPP and imported my live Wordpress code. When I checked my Wordpress site on local environment, there was no page at all.

And I noticed that Wordpress has page data in database. Then How do I make a change in local? Should I import database from live site as well? And after making change update database again?

I’d like to know

1. How other Wordpress developers make change on the code.
2. If they are coding local, how they can check the result?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you also need a copy of the database - especially if your site is using a page builder plugin (eg. Divi).

Comment: @cabrerahector you need the database **regardless** of any page builder. All of WP data is in the database. sodayellos - you need to import the database from your live environment on your local setup. There's not one set way WP developers do local development, but it is usually a combination of a local server, like you have, XAMPP, Docker, etc. If you are coding local, the result is viewing your localhost (whatever port XAMPP defines). This is a really broad question and I highly recommend looking for tutorials on local WP development.

Comment: I know @disinfor, hence why I said "you also need a copy of the database."

Comment: @cabrerahector _especially if your site is using a page builder plugin_ it was that which made me respond. There is no "especially." No matter what, you need a local copy of the database. Either way, OP's question is still too broad for SO.

Comment: Semantics I guess, @disinfor. But yeah, the conclusion is still the same for OP.

Comment: @disinfor cabrerahector Thanks for everyone for answering. I needed to copy DB as well. And I'll learn more about local WP development 

Answer (score -1):

First there is nothing called (**I’m trying to customize my WordPress website**) because that mean you need to customize a DB as will. and if you do that you may break your hole site.
Its called (customize WordPress theme). and that depends what is the customization you want to do. if you want to add page templates or change the style of your site.

you can download a copy of your theme and do it locally as you mentioned using XAMPP and upload the file you worked on again to your host (hosted files). this will be safer and easer to do.

and about (**version control.**) there is nothing like that. you need to do it manually download and upload.

Comment: This answer is **extremely** wrong. "Customize a WP site" is definitely a thing. Yes, primarily we are talking about theme files, but there is nothing wrong with that phrase. Also, there is **definitely** version control - hence using git and GitHub.